# Constructing a field with the roots of the polynomial $x^2-3$ and $F=\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm stuck trying to figure out this problem.

The polynomial $x^2-3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

I know that if $F[x]/f(x)$ is a field since $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial.  I'm not sure how this plays into showing that this allows us to construct a field with the roots of the given polynomial and given field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show $F[\sqrt 3] \simeq F[x]/(x^2-3)$, where $(x^2-3)$ denotes the principal ideal generated by the function. Consider the evaluation homomorphism $\varphi : F[x] \to F[\sqrt 3]$, $\varphi (g) = g(\sqrt 3)$.  Show ker $\varphi = (x^2-3)$ and use the 1st Homo. Theorem.

$F[\sqrt 3]$ is the splitting field of $x^2-3$ over $F=\mathbb Z _5$ since $x^2-3=(x+\sqrt 3)(x+4\sqrt 3)$ in $F[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: What is $f(x+(f(x)))\in F[x]/f(x)$? (Where the $(f(x))$ inside denotes the ideal.)